# Not an ARRAY reference when using Perl's XML::Simple

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I am getting into XML::Simple and have had a problem with the XML::Simple module choking when parsing one record. The perl code is below.....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# use module
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

# create object
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
my $data = $xml->XMLin("owners.xml");

foreach my $e (@{$data->{Owner}})
{
     print $e->{OwnerId}->{OwnerCik}."\n";
     print $e->{OwnerId}->{OwnerName}."\n";
     print "\n";
}
```

When I use this XML, it works beautifully...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ownershipDocument>
    <Owner>
        <OwnerId>
            <OwnerCik>0001234878</OwnerCik>
            <OwnerName>PUBLIC JOHN Q</OwnerName>
        </OwnerId>
    </Owner>
    <Owner>
        <OwnerId>
            <OwnerCik>0001234877</OwnerCik>
            <OwnerName>PUBLIC JANE Q</OwnerName>
        </OwnerId>
    </Owner>
</ownershipDocument>
```

It's when I have a one record that I have issues... the XML below is an example...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ownershipDocument>
    <Owner>
        <OwnerId>
            <OwnerCik>0001234878</OwnerCik>
            <OwnerName>PUBLIC JOHN Q</OwnerName>
        </OwnerId>
    </Owner>
</ownershipDocument>
```

The error I get when parsing this is.....

```
Not an ARRAY reference at ./so_parse.pl line 14.
```

I thought the solution would be to use ForceArray and I changed this to include ForceArray..

```
my $data = $xml->XMLin("so_single.xml", ForceArray=>1);
```

Now I get ......

```
Not a HASH reference at ./so_parse.pl line 16.
```

Admittedly, I'm a little hazy on complex data structures but what I'm trying to solve is how to parse these owners when we only have one.

Any help would be great!
Janie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $data = $xml->XMLin("so_single.xml", ForceArray=>['Owner']);
```

It should only [force the array](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#ForceArray_=%3E_%5B_names_%5D_#_in_-_important) on the 'Owner' elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is logic and normal. In the first XML file, you have multiple owners, and not in the second XML file. When you do

```
my $data = $xml->XMLin("owners.xml");
```

you "convert" the XML in a Perl data structure, and the repeated nodes are in a Perl array, not the others.

What you can do instead :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# use module
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

# create object
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
my $data = $xml->XMLin("owners.xml");

# if $data->{Owner} is an ARRAY ref
if (ref($data->{Owner}) =~ /ARRAY/) {
    foreach my $e (@{$data->{Owner}}) {
         print $e->{OwnerId}->{OwnerCik}."\n";
         print $e->{OwnerId}->{OwnerName}."\n";
         print "\n";
    }
} else {
    print $data->{Owner}->{OwnerId}->{OwnerCik}."\n";
    print $data->{Owner}->{OwnerId}->{OwnerName}."\n";
}
```